# How can I mock cookies in NextJS server components

Tags: next.js, vitest

I'm trying to write a test for a NextJS app that uses cookies. I'm using vitest and I'd like to mock the cookies to see if the conditional rendering works as expected.

```
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
```

Results in the following error when I run `vitest`:

```
Error: Invariant: cookies() expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available.
 ❯ Proxy.cookies node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_@babel+core@7.23.7_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/src/client/components/headers.ts:41:11
 ❯ Home src/app/page.tsx:10:24
      8| 
      9| export default async function Home() {
     10|   const cookiesStore = cookies();
```

I cloned a new project from the [official sample](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/testing/vitest) and modified only the `Home` page as stated above

```
npx create-next-app@latest --example with-vitest with-vitest-app
```

How can I prevent this error and mock the cookies in the test?

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a version of your cookies function and control its behaviour when you're testing. You can use [`vi.mock`](https://vitest.dev/api/vi#vi-mock) for this.

```
import { expect, test, vi } from "vitest";
import { render, screen, within } from "@testing-library/react";
import Home from "../pages/home";

vi.mock("next/headers", async (importOriginal) => {
  return {
    cookies: () => {
      return {
        get: (name: string) => {
          return {
            value: "cookie",
          };
        },
      };
    },
  };
});
    

test("Pages Router", () => {
  render(<Home />);
  const main = within(screen.getByRole("main"));
  expect(...)
  // Your test assertions go here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, you are using `jest.mock` in here which is not part of vitest. However, I was able to make it work because you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks